For every row in table x does its identity column also exist in table y
For every row in table x, insert a correct value into table y; each table will have guid's that match, but table x has some bogus name values.
Table x
field 1     field 2
--------------------
good name   guid 1
good name   guid 2

Table y
field 1    field 2
-------------------
bad name   guid 1
bad name   guid 2

Desired output
field 1    field 2
-------------------
good name  guid 1
good name  guid 2

edit:
this is the statement I believe I need (thanks Bohemian):
UPDATE parts SET sheetname = (select sheetname from sheets where sheets.sheetid = parts.sheetid)

but I am getting the dreaded "operation must use an updateable query" error. The typical cause of which is not having write access which I do  have (and I have  other update and insert queries which work fine). both tables have a primary  key which is not involved in the query. So I am at a loss as to the error. Tried using "distinctrow" also to no avail.

Your example does not help much to explain what you want. Do you want to update the values in y using the matching values in x?

You seem to need an UPDATE statement, not an INSERT. However every database has some unique parts to their SQL implementation - you need to specify the database you actually use. Choose a tag that identifies that database.

Please show us what you tried...

Within that sheets table are the sheetid values unique?

sheetid's are unique

Access treats your UPDATE as non-updatable because it contains a subquery.
Since you reported the sheets.sheetid values are unique, I don't see why you need a subquery.  Just base your UPDATE on an INNER JOIN between the two tables like this:
UPDATE parts INNER JOIN sheets ON parts.sheetid = sheets.sheetid
SET parts.sheetname = sheets.sheetname


To update table_y with the corresponding value in table_x using standard SQL:
update table_y set
field1 = (
  select field1
  from table_x
  where table_x.field2 = table_y.field2
)


thank you Bohemian, I think that will do the trick!

that works! thanks!
